# google api description on city location

Tags: api, google-maps, google-places-api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I search request from google api.
I want to get data description on city or location by latitude or name city.
In language js.

I have use google api or wiki api?

For example[image]

Right box with information on city California and nearby interest place in California top box.

Comment: Does the information have to be in Slovak?

Comment: Yes, I want have information "result" on slovak language. If you have idea then write me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to nearby interest attraction or interest place of city, location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42588096/how-to-nearby-interest-attraction-or-interest-place-of-city-location)