# How to nearby interest attraction or interest place of city, location

Tags: rest, google-api, location, mediawiki-api

How to nearby interest attraction or interest place of city, location?

For example image: top box or right box.
I want get those information.
What have I use? Google Api place or Wiki api?

...and piece request, source code.

Thanks [image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/). There are lots of demos and code examples on the documentation site.